# How to get/filter data between two date by using DataGrid in vb.net WPF and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net

How to get/filter data between two date by using Data Grid in vb.net WPF and MySQL?

```
Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click

    Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    Mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=ronaldo11; database= majlis_cms"


    Dim dtp1 As Date = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value
    Dim dtp2 As Date = datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value

    dt.Clear()

    Try
        Mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String

        query = "Select * from majlis_cms.daily_cash_balancing_report where Date between >= " & dtp1.ToString("yyyy") & "/" & dtp1.ToString("MM") & "/" & dtp1.ToString("dd") & "# and Date <= #" & dtp2.ToString("yyyy") & "/" & dtp2.ToString("MM") & "/" & dtp2.ToString("dd") & "# order by Date "

        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, Mysqlconn)
        da.Fill(dt)


        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No match found")
        End If

    Finally
        Mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
    DataGrid.DataContext = dt
    Load_DataGrid()
End Sub
```

Error message screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Where is error msg screenshot ?

Comment: did you try the same query in mysql itself?

Comment: yes . but i still cant get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it. this is the code.

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class DailyCash
    Private Mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection
    Private COMMAND As New MySqlCommand
    Private dt As New DataTable
    Private da As MySqlDataAdapter
    Private dtp1 As String
    Private dtp2 As String
    Private ds As DataSet

```
Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    Load_DataGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub Load_DataGrid()
    Dim connectionString As String = "server=localhost; database=majlis_cms; userid=root; password=ronaldo11;"

    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * from majlis_cms.daily_cash_balancing_report", connection)
    connection.Open()

    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
    connection.Close()

    dataGrid.DataContext = dt
End Sub

Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    Dim MainWindow As New MainWindow

    MainWindow.Show()
    Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click

    Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    Mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=ronaldo11; database= majlis_cms;"

    Dim dtp1 As Date = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value
    Dim dtp2 As Date = datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value

    dt.Clear()

    Dim query As String
    Mysqlconn.Open()
    query = "Select * from daily_cash_balancing_report where Date between'" & dtp1.ToString("yyyy") & "/" & dtp1.ToString("MM") & "/" & dtp1.ToString("dd") & "' and  '" & dtp2.ToString("yyyy") & "/" & dtp2.ToString("MM") & "/" & dtp2.ToString("dd") & "' order by Date "


    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, Mysqlconn)

    da.Fill(dt)
    ds = New DataSet

    dataGrid.DataContext = dt
    Mysqlconn.Close()


    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No match found")
    End If

    Mysqlconn.Dispose()


End Sub
```

[enter screenshot 1 (before filter) description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfIMI.png)

[enter screenshot 2 (after filter) description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvVBq.png)